# EHCache : Get cache value in jsp page

Tags: ehcache

I have stored a list in ehCache from my J2EE Model. In one of my view(.jsp page), I want to access the stored list directly from ehCache. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code of yours needs to put that value on the context of the page, Ehcache does not have any magic in it to make that happen.